# The 'int' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python

I have searched for nearly an hour online, but can't find anything. But I digress, line 6 keeps on returning `TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable`. Please help me identify what causes this.

```
def __reassigner__(allL, currentRow, currentSpace):
    changingRow=currentRow+1
    newl=[-1]*24
    while changingRow<8:
        distance = changingRow-currentRow
        newl[8:15]=allL[changingRow[0:7]]  #Line 6, this one
        if newl[currentSpace]==-1:
           newl[currentSpace]= currentRow
         if newl[currentSpace-distance]==-1:
           newl[currentSpace-distance]= currentRow
        if newl[currentSpace+distance]==-1:
           newl[currentSpace+distance]= currentRow
        allL[changingRow[0:7]]=newl[8:15]
        changingRow+=1
    return(allL)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but names \_\_surrounded\_\_ by double-underscores are supposed to be used for Python's built-in functionality, and the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) forbids creating your own.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `changingRow` is an integer, but you try to slice it with `changingRow[0:7]`. Since this operation is not allowed on ints, you get the error.

I don't know what your intention was with that line. Maybe `allL` is a list of lists and you were going for `allL[changingRow][0:7]`?

Comment: Thanks! You diagnosed that awesomely, and that part of the code now works. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

`changingRow` in your code seems to be an integer (I assume that after line saying `changingRow=currentRow+1`). Unfortunately, in line 6, you try to obtain: `changingRow[0:7]`, which doesn't work, since you're trying to access your integer value as if it was an array.

Answer (score 0):

`changingRow` is an integer value. `changingRow[0:7]` would extract the first 7 elements of a list-like ("subscriptable") object, but an `int` has no such "elements" like the ones in lists and strings have.

What are you trying to achieve with `changingRow[0:7]`?

Answer (score 0):

changingRow is an integer, you can't take indeces 0-7 from it

Answer (score 0):

You can't access write `changingRow[0:7]` because changingRow is an integer.  If you must access it using slice notation (for the first 8 digits or something) you can do `str(changingRow)[0:7]`, but you probably have a design problem.